# Base64 image woes on drupal

Tags: image, base64, drupal-8

This is how I'm storing the image in the database:

```
$qr = NULL;
if ($file = file_save_upload('qr', $validators, FALSE, 0)) {
  $type = pathinfo($file->getFileUri(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $qr = file_get_contents($file->getFileUri());
  $base64 = 'data:image/'.$type.';base64,'.base64_encode($qr);
}
```

Note that the `data` at the beginning of the base64 is there. Then I retrieve the data from the database, and place in inside of an image tag, like so:

```
$form['qr'] = [
  '#prefix' => '<img width="100" height="100" src="'.$document[0]['QR_Image'].'"></img>',
];
```

However, when I go to inspect the element, I get a broken image symbol, and the source reads `image/png;base64,...`, without the data part. When I type in data at the beginning of the source attribute, the image shows up.

Any idea why Drupal cuts off the data part of my data block?

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda basic, but this works:

```
$form['qr'] = [
  '#markup' => new FormattableMarkup('<img width="100" height="100" src="data::src"></img>', [':src' => $document[0]['QR_Image']])
];
```

I'd rather it didn't chop off the first `data` though.